# can someone tell me what the chances are of this hand that me and my poker boys played tonight?? quads and a full house

Tags: odds, full-house

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23xhlYJEvpo&feature=youtu.be

P1 was dealt AA vs P2 was dealt QQ
Flop A 4 Q 
River Q
Turn 6
does anyone actually know the odds of the quads aswell as a full house being on the table 
P2 checked on the River and P1 went all in lol.. such a bad way to lose

Answer (score 0):

QQ AA is 2.21627112383415E-005

board 
A 2 ways
QQ one way
three other 13244 ways

possible boards 2118760

board alone 0.0125016519

in total 2.77070501274892E-007 = 1 / 3609190

If any quad and full house from paired hole cards then just multiply by 13 * 12

Since I had it out calculated the odds of two quad with pocket pair and that is 1/ 37395

see [this](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/9202/combinations-and-poker-probability/9203#9203)

Comment: I get frustrated with posts and the person never comes back.