# Combinations and poker probability

Tags: probability

How to calculate poker odds using [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)?

Comment: Once you know the combinations, you just divide the number of favorable combination by the number of unfavorable ones. The hard part is calculating the combinations though.

Comment: This should probably be converted into a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I got tired of explaining [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) in answers so just making one post.

With multiple cards simple fractions don't work.

Combination is how many ways you can make the combination.
Like 52 take 5 or 52 take 2

In Excel it is combin(n, k)

How many possible hole cards combin(52, 2) = 1326

On the river your opponent can have combin(45, 2) = 990

Odds of a pocket pair
13 rank * combin(4, 2) / 1326 = 1 / 17

Suited
4 * combin(13, 2) / 1326 = 4.25

Above you can do with fraction but from a pair chance to hit quads
quad is 1 way
then 3 cards from 48
combin(48, 3) / combin(50, 5) = 1 / 122.5

trips or better from pair
combin(2, 1) * combin(48, 4) / combin(50, 5) = 1 / 5.4444444444

for [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability)